# Modifying CakePHP-resident Wordpress Redirects using mod_rewrite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

I have a CakePHP site that contains a vanilla Wordpress installation.  It lives in `/app/webroot/blog/`.  The problem I'm having is a strange one.

I have the site configured, through mod rewrite, to redirect all requests to `/app/webroot/blog` to `/blog/`.  The reason for this is that Wordpress was either throwing errors or displaying no content when the user visited it via the `app/webroot` path and it works just fine if you visit it at `/blog/`.  It would also redirect the user to `/app/webroot/blog` if they attempted to visit `/blog` without a trailing slash, so we added that as well.  Here are the mod_rewrite rules we're using to accomplish this:

```
RewriteRule    ^blog$ blog/ [L]
RewriteRule    ^app/webroot/blog/(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]
```

When the user attempts to visit the admin section of Wordpress but is not authenticated, it sends them to the `/wp-login.php` page and sends along a query string parameter called `redirect_to` that contains the URL the user was originally trying to access before being asked to authenticate. This URL contains the full path (`/app/webroot/blog/...`) instead of just going to `/blog`, even if the original request was a page within `/blog`.  If the user successfully authenticates, then the user is sent back to the login page as though nothing happened (no error messages, etc.).

I would assume that the second mod_rewrite rule listed above would rectify the issue, but it doesn't seem to be.

I hope I've explained this thoroughly, please let me know if I can provide additional information that I may have forgotten.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

have you tried checking wordpress options in wp database. there are two options you should make sure that are correct. **siteurl** and **home**. both should be http://yoursite.com/blog

Answer (score 0):

What's your document root directory? **Make app/webroot/ your document root directory** and you won't need any additional rewrite rules, because CakePHP's default rewrite rules already have rules for existing files and directories:

So your /app/webroot/index.php will be you application entry point with address .../ ,

and app/webroot/blog/ will be wordpress entry point with address .../blog/

Default rewrite rules are enough for this configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # this will go to your blog dir, if it exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] # this is CakePHP app
```